# how to set the encoding of MATLAB m-files to be UTF8

Tags: matlab, utf-8, latex

I want to insert an m-file into LaTeX, and there are Chinese characters in my m-files, so I need the encoding of m-files to be UTF8.I have searched for some materials on the web, and I found the MATLAB command: **slCharacterEncoding**. So, I closed all the m-files and input the **slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')**in the command window. But when I opened the m-file using Notepad++, the encoding of the m-file with Chinese characters still is **GB2312**, and the m-files without Chinese characters is normal (UTF8).
how should I do to set the matlab editor to be UTF8 encoding? thanks

I have searched for some materials on the web, and I found the MATLAB command: **slCharacterEncoding**. So, I closed all the m-files and input the **slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')**in the command window.

in matlab command, I input

```matlab
slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')
```

in my .tex file, I input

```
\input{main.m}
```

I expect the matlab  m-file **main.m** coding in UTF8.

Comment: It is not the file itself that needs to be marked as UTF-8, you need to instruct LaTeX to interpret the file as UTF-8. But LaTeX itself does not handle UNICODE inputs, so you need to use XeTeX or some similar variant that uses UNICODE.

Comment: @CrisLuengo   thanks, I indeed  have used the XeTeX but when I compile the .tex file, the Chinese chacteraters in the **main.m** 
 file displayed the messy code. Frthermore, when I converted the encoding of main.m into UTF8 using Notepad++,  this time  after compiling the .tex file, the Chinese characters are normal. I want to know whether we can convert the matlab m file in UTF8 when using matlab directly? so  we need not to do that in notepad++ troubly. thanks very much.

Comment: At least on Linux and MacOS (I haven't used Windows in a long time) there is no difference between a file encoded UTF-8 or any other way. It is the software reading it that must know how the file is encoded and interpret it appropriately. That is, saving a text file containing only ASCII characters as UTF-8 or as ISO 8859-1 give you a bite-by-byte identical file. IMO this is a question solely related to LaTeX, not to MATLAB. Here is how to tell XeTeX what encoding to use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153833/problem-with-xetex-input-and-output-encoding

Comment: You might want to consider asking this question on tex.stackexchange.com instead, there's more people there that know LaTeX than here.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  okay,Thanks very much. You are very nice. I will go and see that.

Comment: @sunshine Question is well placed in here. Matlab has several issues with setting UTF-8.